# Separar resultados em grupos

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho 3 tabelas: NOME,TAMANHO E DATA:

```
NOME      DATA         TAMANHO 
Armário   1657050960   Pequeno 
Armário   1657051020   Grande 
Armário   1657051013   Médio 
Janela    1657051012   Pequeno
Janela    1657051011   Médio 
Armário   1657051010   Gigante
```

E preciso deixar eles assim no while:

```html
<div>
<div>ARMÁRIO:</div>
<div>Pequeno - Data: 1657050960</div>
<div>Grande - Data: 1657051020</div>
<div>Médio - Data: 1657051013</div>
<div>Gigante - Data: 1657051010</div>
<div>

<div>
<div>JANELA:</div>
<div>Pequeno -  Data: 1657051012</div>
<div>Médio - Data: 1657051011</div>
<div>
```

E que os campos de TAMANHO sejam ORDER BY DATA DESC , preciso complementar:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos";
$sql = $banco_de_dados->query($sql);
if ($sql->num_rows > 0) { 
while($dados = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {

}
}
```

Alguma sugestão galerinha?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

```
$sql = "Select * from produtos order by nome,data DESC";
$query = $banco_de_dados->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$array= $query->fetchAll;
Foreach($array as $objeto){
  echo "<div>$objeto['nome']</div>";
 while($objeto['nome']==$nome){
   echo "<div>$objeto['tamanho'] - $objeto['data']</div>";
   $nome = $objeto['nome'];
 }
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Opps, infelizmente não funcionou.